# SQL Server 2008 Case When Cast

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having trouble figuring this statement out. It seems that SQL Server is still executing the `THEN` part in the `CASE WHEN` statement. Please see this query.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN ISNUMERIC('INC') = 1 
       THEN CAST('INC' as numeric(10,2)) 
       ELSE 'FALSE' 
   END AS foo
```

SQL Server is returning

> "Error converting data type varchar to numeric"

From this query it should return `FALSE` and not return an Error since the `THEN` part was not executed.

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Thanks everyone! I should really consider to return the same datatype next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning two different data types from the same column. So try this one -

```
DECLARE @value CHAR(3)
SET @value = 66

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@value) = 1 
        THEN CAST(CAST(@value AS NUMERIC(10,2)) AS VARCHAR(30))
        ELSE 'FALSE'
    END AS foo
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because, your query is trying to

```
CAST 'FALSE' as Numeric(10,2)
```

Try this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC('INC') = 1 THEN 
CAST(CAST('INC' as numeric(10,2)) AS varchar(5))
ELSE 'FALSE' END AS foo
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one branch of you `CASE` branches returns `VARCHAR` and the other a number.

Try the following:

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC('INC') = 1 
    THEN CAST(CAST('INC' AS NUMERIC(10,2)) AS NVARCHAR)
    ELSE 'FALSE' 
END AS foo
```